# EntityManager persist() method does not insert record to database => SEVERE: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

Tags: jpa, entity

I have problem with using EntityManager persist() method.
I am using JSF2.0, glassfish 3, JPA and hibernate, i am not using spring.

I try to add events in an events table with the method persist, but EntityManager persist() method does not insert record to database and i have this error message =>

SEVERE: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTxRequiredCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:163)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.flush(EntityManagerWrapper.java:411)
    at dao.EvenementDao.addEvenement(EvenementDao.java:128).

```
@ManagedBean
@Stateless
public class EvenementDao implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3343483942392617877L;
/**
 * 
 */


private List<TEvenement>  listeEvenement;
private List<SelectItem> listeSelectItemEvnt;
private TEvenement tevenement ;




public EvenementDao() {

}


@PersistenceUnit(unitName="GA2010-ejbPU-dev")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;



@PostConstruct
private void init() {

    tevenement = new TEvenement();

}



public List<TEvenement> getListeEvenement() {
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<TEvenement> requete = m.createNamedQuery("TEvenement.findPrivateOther", 
    TEvenement.class);
    listeEvenement = requete.getResultList();

    return listeEvenement;
}

public TEvenement getEvenement() {
    return tevenement;
}



public void setEvenement(TEvenement evenement) {
    this.tevenement = evenement;
}



public void addEvenement(){
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                          getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    Integer codeUser = (Integer) session.getAttribute("codeUser");
    tevenement.setUtilCreation(codeUser);

    System.out.println("je rentre dans addevenemnt");
    try{




        System.out.println("i persist "+ em);

            em.persist(tevenement);
            em.flush();
        System.out.println(tevenement.getDetailsEvenement());

        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Evenement ajouté avec succès.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

So, this is not working, but the progam enter in the fonction addEvenement , FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Evenement ajouté avec succès."); returns me the message as if it was working.
i thouht it was due to my entityMAnager but in fact an ohter function works fine with the same Entity manager so i dont understand.

```
**public List<TEvenement> getListeEvenement()** {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<TEvenement> requete =     em.createNamedQuery("TEvenement.findPrivateOther", TEvenement.class);
    listeEvenement = requete.getResultList();

    return listeEvenement;
}
```

this one works fine, the only difference is  that in this case the query is a select and in the other case it's a persist so a query that impact the database.

the code of the entity :

@Entity
@Table(name="t_evenements")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="TEvenement.findAll", query="SELECT evnt FROM TEvenement evnt"), 
        @NamedQuery(name="TEvenement.findPrivateOther", query="SELECT evnt FROM TEvenement evnt WHERE evnt.typeEvenement = 6 OR evnt.typeEvenement = 7")})
public class TEvenement implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1908959833491896991L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="REF_EVENEMENT", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer refEvenement;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="DATE_DEBUT_EVENEMENT")
private Date dateDebutEvenement;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="DATE_FIN_EVENEMENT")
private Date dateFinEvenement;

@Column(name="DETAILS_EVENEMENT")
private String detailsEvenement;

@Column(name="IS_EVERYDAY")
private byte isEveryday;

@Column(name="RAPPEL_EVENEMENT")
private int rappelEvenement;

public Integer getUtilEvenement() {
    return utilEvenement;
}

public void setUtilEvenement(Integer utilEvenement) {
    this.utilEvenement = utilEvenement;
}

@Column(name="TITRE_EVENEMENT")
private String titreEvenement;

@Column(name="TYPE_EVENEMENT")
private String typeEvenement;

@Column(name="UTIL_COPIE_EVENEMENT")
private Integer utilCopieEvenement;

@Column(name="UTIL_EVENEMENT")
private Integer utilEvenement;

@Column(name="HEURE_EVENEMENT")
private String heureEvenement;

@Column(name="UTIL_CREATION")
private Integer  utilCreation;


public String getHeureEvenement() {
    return heureEvenement;
}

public void setHeureEvenement(String heureEvenement) {
    this.heureEvenement = heureEvenement;
}

public TEvenement() {
}

public Integer getRefEvenement() {
    return this.refEvenement;
}

public void setRefEvenement(int refEvenement) {
    this.refEvenement = refEvenement;
}

public Date getDateDebutEvenement() {
    return this.dateDebutEvenement;
}

public Integer getUtilCreation() {
    return utilCreation;
}

public void setUtilCreation(Integer utilCreation) {
    this.utilCreation = utilCreation;
}

public void setUtilCopieEvenement(Integer utilCopieEvenement) {
    this.utilCopieEvenement = utilCopieEvenement;
}

public void setDateDebutEvenement(Date dateDebutEvenement) {
    this.dateDebutEvenement = dateDebutEvenement;
}

public Date getDateFinEvenement() {
    return this.dateFinEvenement;
}

public void setDateFinEvenement(Date dateFinEvenement) {
    this.dateFinEvenement = dateFinEvenement;
}

public String getDetailsEvenement() {
    return this.detailsEvenement;
}

public void setDetailsEvenement(String detailsEvenement) {
    this.detailsEvenement = detailsEvenement;
}

public byte getIsEveryday() {
    return this.isEveryday;
}

public void setIsEveryday(byte isEveryday) {
    this.isEveryday = isEveryday;
}

public int getRappelEvenement() {
    return this.rappelEvenement;
}

public void setRappelEvenement(int rappelEvenement) {
    this.rappelEvenement = rappelEvenement;
}

public String getTitreEvenement() {
    return this.titreEvenement;
}

public void setTitreEvenement(String titreEvenement) {
    this.titreEvenement = titreEvenement;
}

public String getTypeEvenement() {
    return this.typeEvenement;
}

public void setTypeEvenement(String typeEvenement) {
    this.typeEvenement = typeEvenement;
}

public Integer getUtilCopieEvenement() {
    return this.utilCopieEvenement;
}

public void setUtilCopieEvenement(int utilCopieEvenement) {
    this.utilCopieEvenement = utilCopieEvenement;
}
```

}

Do anyone have a idea what am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

The difference isn't that you call persist, the difference is that you call em.flush() which as the error states, requires the EntityManager be joined to a transaction.  Makes sure your getListeEvenement() method is wrapped in a transaction, or start one depending on your setup.

Comment: there are many examples of getting or starting a transaction on the server.  A quick example would be to use @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) in your bean, with some other examples described here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions

Comment: @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)  => this do not works maybe it is because i tried to inject a class and not an interface i read this but i dont know if it is up to date==>  http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/no_xml_dependency_injection_jpa .  In the article says : " Common error: you cannot inject classes in EJB 3.0, but only interfaces. This will change in EJB 3.1..." is it still true?