# How do I setup SessionFactory when using JPA2 with Hibernate 4 and Spring 3?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Inside a controller my code was not persisting when I called .persist. I've also included my AppConfig for reference as well as my gradle dependencies. This is all on Tomcat7.

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="main">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dirtylibs"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Gradle

```
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '3.2.5.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '3.2.5.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.3.0.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.3.0.Final'
runtime group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.3.0'
runtime group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.3.0'
runtime group: 'mysql', name:'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.26'
```

AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AppConfig.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); //This is some wierdness I needed to do because the mysql driver wasn't being picked up correctly
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
@Controller
public class SampleController {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
    @RequestMapping("home/test/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Integer> getMessagesTest(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
        entityManager.persist(phrase);
        return Arrays.asList(phrase.getId());
    }

}
```

According to

[EntityManager persist() method does not insert record to database => SEVERE: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150563/entitymanager-persist-method-does-not-insert-record-to-database-severe-jav)

To persist data to a database using an entity manager I need to have it wrapped up in a transaction, which will call .flush() for me at the end of the transaction. Which means I need to add @Transaction to my controller, which I did. Now it looks like this.

```
@RequestMapping("home/test/{id}")
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public List<Integer> getMessagesTest(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
    entityManager.persist(phrase);
    return Arrays.asList(phrase.getId());
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.html

Once I do that, I get the following exception.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined
```

Okay, no problem. It looks like the [Hibernate 4 HibernateTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html) will do the job. Once I started to configure the HibernateTransactionManager in my AppConfig I realized I also needed a SessionFactory.

I very confused by all the options for creating a SessionFactory, and how it relates to my persistence.xml

My main question is **how should I construct my session factory given my current setup?**

Looking at the Spring docs it looks like I have to repeat all the information from my persistence.xml which seems really wrong to me. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/orm.html#orm-hibernate

Any help would be much appreciated, including critique of the current setup. I really want to stick with the Java config, and avoid as much XML as possible. I'd even like to move away from the persistence-config.xml as described here, but I wanted to wait until it was working before trying that.

http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/10/spring-3-1-m2-configuration-enhancements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bozho's post over at [Best Way to Inject Hibernate Session by Spring 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699381/best-way-to-inject-hibernate-session-by-spring-3) gave me the information I needed to get it all tied together. I still haven't figured out if I need the persistence.xml, but now I'm recording entities to the database.

My new AppConfig now looks like this

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);
    return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
BasicDataSource basicDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dirtylibs");
    basicDataSource.setUsername("root");
    basicDataSource.setPassword("password");

    return basicDataSource;
}


@Bean
JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

I had to pull in another dependency for the BasicDataSource which came from Apache. Here are the Gradle coordinates.

```
compile group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version: '1.4'
```